# Merge overlapping time intervals based on priority and type - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to solve an issue where I want to merge overlapping ranges while respecting priority and type. I have start_time and stop_time for each interval, priority and type. Higher priorities must override lower priorities. The type must be appreciated not to mix periods of different types.

```
declare @t table (type int, priority int,  start_date  datetime,  end_date datetime);

insert into @t select 1, 1, '2023-01-01', '2023-01-10'
insert into @t select 1, 1, '2023-01-08', '2023-01-14'
insert into @t select 1, 2, '2023-01-12', '2023-01-20'
insert into @t select 1, 1, '2023-01-17', '2023-01-22'
insert into @t select 1, 3, '2023-01-18', '2023-01-25'
insert into @t select 1, 2, '2023-01-23', '2023-02-05'
insert into @t select 1, 3, '2023-02-07', '2023-02-15'
insert into @t select 1, 1, '2023-02-10', NULL

insert into @t select 2, 1, '2023-01-01', '2023-01-20'
insert into @t select 2, 2, '2023-01-10', '2023-01-15'
insert into @t select 2, 3, '2023-01-18', NULL;
```

Expected result:

```
  Type  Prio    Dates
    1  |  1  |  2023-01-01 - 2023-01-11 
    1  |  2  |  2023-01-12 - 2023-01-17 
    1  |  3  |  2023-01-18 - 2023-01-25 
    1  |  2  |  2023-01-26 - 2023-02-05 
    1  |  3  |  2023-02-07 - 2023-01-15 
    1  |  1  |  2023-02-16 - NULL       
    
    2  |  1  |  2023-01-01 - 2023-01-09 
    2  |  2  |  2023-01-10 - 2023-01-15 
    2  |  1  |  2023-01-16 - 2023-01-17 
    2  |  3  |  2023-01-18 - NULL
```

I found an example that works with just the type, ignoring the priority column. However, I need it to work looking at the type and priority columns.

```
with STARTs as 
( 
    select distinct type, start_date 
    from @t as t1 
    where not exists (select * from @t as t2 
                      where t2.type = t1.type 
                        and t2.start_date < t1.start_date 
                        and t2.end_date >= t1.start_date) 
), 
ENDs as 
( 
    select distinct type, end_date 
    from @t as t1 
    where not exists (select * from @t as t2 
                      where t2.type = t1.type 
                        and t2.end_date > t1.end_date 
                        and t2.start_date <= t1.end_date) 
) 
select 
    type, start_date, 
    (select min(end_date) 
     from ENDs as e 
     where e.type = s.type 
       and end_date >= start_date) as end_date 
from 
    STARTs as s;
```

Comment: What's the logic if the third row period would be :

prio: 2 from: 2023-01-12  to: 2023-03-20
ie, it's overlappning a lot of other overlaps?

Comment: Oh i see, from the second type, it follows that such overlapper should continue after others is done. Very tricky